# Отрисовка циклоиды на ZedGraph/Chart

Tags: c#, winforms, геометрия, диаграммы, zedgraph

Встал перед вопросом, есть простенькая формула выражающая координату Х графика кривой [Циклоида](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A6%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B0). (от нас требуется только задать радиус??)

```
return r* Math.Acos((r - y) / r) - Math.Sqrt(2*r*y - Math.Pow(y,2));
```

Рисую так:

```
for (double y = ymin; y <= ymax; y += 1)
{
 list.Add(CountIt(y, r),y);
}
```

[image: На изображении только первые пол периода циклоиды]

Кривая просто рисуется постепенно уходящей куда-то вверх, я подумал, что возможно я никак не учел период, либо то, что `Acos` возвращает значение в радианах? Поэксперементировал, но ничего не вышло.

Comment: Понятия не имею что за ZedGraph, но возможно вам надо подобрать масштаб осям?

Comment: @D-side, тот же Chart. Дело не в масштабе

Comment: Приложите в вопрос картинку с этой "странной линией", пожалуйста. И поясните, почему вы так уверены, что дело не в масштабе.

Comment: @D-side, от части разобрался, рисует только первые пол периода. ZedGraph позволяет играть с масштабом прямо при работе приложения

Comment: @D-side, если принципиально, приложил изображение.

Comment: а что за параметры ymin и ymax? мб до ymax доходит и перестает считать следующие точки?

Comment: (1) а разве не [похоже](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/69/Cycloid_f.gif?uselang=ru)? (2) вы ведь понимаете, что Х(У) для одного и того же У должно быть **несколько** возможных Х ? :)

Comment: А, ну так блин, арккосинус для значений меньше минус единицы не определен. т.е. для всех  y > 2r в вашем случае

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы что-то где то попутали с периодами. У меня после мытарств получилось следующее

```
private void DrawPlotDek()
{       
    float r = 100;

    float ymin = 0;
    float ymax = r*8;

    for (var y = ymin; y < ymax; y += 0.01f)
    {           
        var x = r* Math.Acos((r - y) / r) - Math.Sqrt(2*r*y - Math.Pow(y,2));
        SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);
        SetPixel((float)(x + 2 * Math.PI * r), (float)y);

        x = r * (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Acos((r - y) / r)) + Math.Sqrt(2 * r * y - Math.Pow(y, 2)) + r * 3/2 * Math.PI;
        SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);           
    }
}
```

Как оно получилось - эксперименты и осколки воспоминаний из тригонометрии.

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Имхо, гораздо понятней считать по параметрическим координатам.

```
private void DrawPlot()
{
    float tmin = 0;
    float tmax = 100;
    float r = 100;

    for(var t=tmin; t<tmax; t+=0.0001f)
    {
        var x = r*t - r*Math.Sin(t);
        var y = r - r*Math.Cos(t);

        SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);
    }
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если наложить их друг на друга

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Полный код

```
void Main()
{
    var f = new MyForm();
    f.Show();
    f.Draw();
}

class MyForm : Form
{
    private Graphics _g;
    private Brush _b;

    public MyForm()
    {
        this.Height = 500;
        this.Width = 950;

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

        Draw();
    }

    public void Draw()
    {
        _g = this.CreateGraphics();
        DrawAxes();             

        _b = Brushes.Red;       
        DrawPlot();     

        _b = Brushes.Green;
        DrawPlotDek();
    }   

    private void DrawPlot()
    {
        float tmin = 0;
        float tmax = 100;
        float r = 100;

        for(var t=tmin; t<tmax; t+=0.0001f)
        {
            var x = r*t - r*Math.Sin(t);
            var y = r - r*Math.Cos(t);

            SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);
        }
    }

    private void DrawPlotDek()
    {       
        float r = 100;

        float ymin = 0;
        float ymax = r*8;

        for (var y = ymin; y < ymax; y += 0.01f)
        {           
            var x = r* Math.Acos((r - y) / r) - Math.Sqrt(2*r*y - Math.Pow(y,2));
            SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);
            SetPixel((float)(x + 2 * Math.PI * r), (float)y);

            x = r * (Math.PI / 2 - Math.Acos((r - y) / r)) + Math.Sqrt(2 * r * y - Math.Pow(y, 2)) + r * 3/2 * Math.PI;
            SetPixel((float)x, (float)y);           
        }
    }

    public void DrawAxes()
    {
        _g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 25, 400, 700, 400);
        _g.DrawLine(Pens.Blue, 50, 25, 50, 800);
    }

    private void SetPixel(float x, float y) 
    {
        y = - y + 400;
        x += 50;        
        _g.FillRectangle(_b, x, y, 1, 1);   
    }
}
```